# How to add rows to Vaadin table from a Map<String,Map<Date,Statistics>>?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a Collection as:

```
Map<String,Map<Date,Statistics>> map;
```

Statistics look something like this:

```
    private final Date day;
    private int count;
    private long totalTime;
    private Map<Integer, BigDecimal> averagesMap = new HashMap<Integer, BigDecimal>();
```

So entries and values for **map** is like:

```
nameOne, 03.03.2015, statisticsOne
nameOne, 03.04.2015, statisticsTwo
nameTwo, 03.02.2014, statisticsThree
```

etc..

And lets say **statisticsOne** look like this:

```
day = 03.03.2015
count = 5
totalTime = 50
avaragesMap = {3:20;5:70}
```

Now how can I add a row to a Vaadin Table so I see something like this:

```
nameOne 03.03.2015 5 50 3 20
nameOne 03.03.2015 5 50 5 70
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a wrapper class arround your Map averagesMap structure, which can return something like List

That way you could use the BeanItemContainer to show your content.